# Does archiving root directory archive additional mounted disk directories?

Tags: linux, tar, aws

I am trying to archive a bunch of systems using tar. In order to do so, I am planning to run tar on each of the devices listed by `df` command's output (except tmpfs).

Since the non-root devices are mounted inside root directory (like /opt or /data), I am unsure if running a tar command on the root ("/") would also include the contents of such devices?

If yes, is there a way to skip these devices, as I would like to keep separate archives for separate devices.

Commands I am using currently (example):

```
tar zcf /archive/root_dir.tar /
tar zcf /archive/opt.tar /opt
```

***P.S. (Context):***
I am writing a script to archive data in a bunch of instances AMIs in AWS and upload them to S3 Deep Archive.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkPlotnick, although that question concerns with rsnapshot, I see that in tar man page there's an option for --one-file-system. Does that mean the if this flag is not mentioned, all the contents of mounted devices are included in the root archive too?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong link. Will find the link to a tar question. Yes, if you don't use --one-file-system, tar will copy everything in a file tree even if they're on other mounted filesystems.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkPlotnick, I think that solves my question.